# ASP.NET Core Kestrel dynamic port

Tags: asp.net-core

Can we assign dynamic port to Kestrel instead of this in project.json?

"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel server.urls=http://localhost:5001"

I'm planning to use docker to deploy the code, and for that I would like it to take the port assigned either via a "0" value specified like this http://0.0.0.0:0 or some other way. I can then detect the port from docker and then use the load balancer to point to it.

Please let me know.

Comment: Can you keep the container port 5001 and let Docker assign a host port? If you do this, the application inside the container can still listen to 0.0.0.0:5001 but externally you'd access the container using the assigned host port.

Comment: OK, but still I would like to see how to pass the port via cmand line at least, as local host:(PORT), docker is one of the cases I wanted this scenario. For ex, I also want to test outside of docker with a load balancer,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`web` is just an alias for `Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel server.urls=http://localhost:5001`

This means you can start the app on any port via the command line like this...

```
dnx Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel server.urls=http://localhost:12345
```

You can also use environment variables. In bash...

```
$ MY_PORT=33333
$ dnx Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel server.urls=http://localhost:$MY_PORT
Hosting environment: Production
Now listening on: http://localhost:33333
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Comment: Is there a way to add listening URLs while app is running?